# Getting data inside CLR Procedure from different server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, sqlclr

I have a CLR Procedure that opens a connection to a server, let's say SERVER2, and gets some data, processes it and returns a table.

```
[SqlFunction(
   DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
   FillRowMethodName = "List_FillRow",
   TableDefinition = "Date datetime, Quantity int")]
public static IEnumerable ListCount(...)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStringToSERVER2))
  { ... }
  return list;
}
```

This CLR Procedure is run from an SQL Stored Procedure that runs on SERVER1.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Reports_NumaraSpalariJetWash]
BEGIN
    DECLARE curs CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR   

    SELECT ...

    OPEN curs  

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs   
    INTO ...;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO ...
                    (...)
        SELECT Date, Quantity
        FROM            dbo.ListCount(...)

        FETCH NEXT FROM curs   
        INTO ...;
    END
END
```

I get the errors: `"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction context in use by another session."` In results window this error appears multiple times, I guess once for every loop into FETCH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing an `INSERT...SELECT` should result in a system-generated Transaction to bind the `INSERT` and `SELECT` together as an atomic operation. The default behavior of `SqlConnection`, starting in .NET 4.0 or 4.5 is for `Enlist` to be `True` whereas it had defaulted to `False` in prior versions of the .NET Framework. When `Enlist` is `True`, the new connection will attempt to join the existing Transaction.

Try adding `Enlist=False;` to the Connection String.

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit [SQLCLR.org](https://sqlclr.org/?ref=so_50451316).

Comment: This is something to remember, for future reference. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @AlinI Yer welcome. I just added a little bit of explanation and a link for additional SQLCLR resources :-) Also, could you please add the exact error message to the question. The initial part with the "Message X, Level Y, etc"...will help others find this more easily. Thanks.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky,
This solution worked for me as well.

I have a similar setup and the error message throws was:

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "udf_<My Custom Method>": System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction context in use by another session.